# In pfSense what is the meaning of the "Target Categories" and "Target Categories for off-time" columns in the Groups ACL Screen?

Tags: acl, squid, pfsense

In SquidGuard within pfSense 2.3.1 in the `Groups ACL` screen there are two columns in the `Target Rules List` `Target Categories` and `Target Categories for off-time`.  Each value in the row has the values `allow`, `deny`, `whitelist` and `---`.

Why are there two columns and what do they mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  After looking at the code that is generated and referencing the Squid Guardian website for some examples, it became clear to me that the `Target Categories` column contains the blacklist / whitelist rules that are applied when the acl is within the specified time period, and the `Target Categories for off-time` are the blacklist / whitelist rules that are applied when the acl is outside the time period specified.

## Target Rules Syntax

Copying the `Target Rules` text tells all (provided you've already saved it, it isn't updated automatically when changing the values...)

It usually looks like this:

```
<black-lists applied inside time frame> all|deny [ <black-lists applied outside time frame> all|deny ]
```

The syntax works like this,

- Anything outside of the brackets is what is applied inside the time frame.

  - `<black-lists applied inside time frame>`
- Anything inside the brackets is what is applied outside the time frame.

  - `<black-lists applied inside time frame>`
- The `all` or `deny` at the end states that after the rest of the lists have been run through without a hit (left to right), do you want to allow all the other sites to be accessed, or do you want all the other sites to be denied?

### Prefixes:

```
Applies to all specified black lists
! = Deny
  = allow
^ = whitelist
```

## Example

Now I imagine that I'm over complicating this a bit (there must be a less verbose syntax), and that if I learned more about the allow as opposed to whitelist syntax there would be some way to use the defaults, but I haven't looked into that yet, so here is what I understand:

Suppose that when you want things set outside of the time range you want the following blacklists to be in effect and any other sites are free game:

- blk_BL_adv
- blk_BL_aggressive
- blk_BL_dating
- blk_BL_drugs
- blk_BL_gamble
- blk_BL_hacking
- blk_BL_movies
- blk_BL_news
- blk_BL_politics
- blk_BL_porn
- blk_BL_radiotv
- blk_BL_socialnet
- blk_BL_spyware
- blk_BL_warez

...and you want anything else to be accessible...then you'd put `all` at the end.

To see this in action you would have everything between the brackets:

```
[ !blk_BL_adv !blk_BL_aggressive !blk_BL_dating !blk_BL_drugs !blk_BL_gamble !blk_BL_hacking !blk_BL_movies !blk_BL_news !blk_BL_politics !blk_BL_porn !blk_BL_radiotv !blk_BL_socialnet !blk_BL_spyware !blk_BL_warez all ]
```

Note that there are only `!` (deny) and no  (allow) and no `^` (whitelist)

---

Now suppose that during the time period we would like to allow access to the following, but still keep our off-time blacklist rules in play:

- blk_BL_movies
- blk_BL_news
- blk_BL_politics
- blk_BL_socialnet

Then we copy the values from our off-time list and replace the `!` (deny) with `^` (whitelist) on only the entries listed above.  The rest of them remain `!` deny.

The list outside the brackets then becomes

```
!blk_BL_adv !blk_BL_aggressive !blk_BL_dating !blk_BL_drugs !blk_BL_gamble !blk_BL_hacking ^blk_BL_movies ^blk_BL_news ^blk_BL_politics !blk_BL_porn !blk_BL_radiotv ^blk_BL_socialnet !blk_BL_spyware !blk_BL_warez all
```

...and also there is an `all` at the end to of the list to allow the rest of the sites.

So when we throw it all together we have:

```
 !blk_BL_adv !blk_BL_aggressive !blk_BL_dating !blk_BL_drugs !blk_BL_gamble !blk_BL_hacking ^blk_BL_movies ^blk_BL_news ^blk_BL_politics !blk_BL_porn !blk_BL_radiotv ^blk_BL_socialnet !blk_BL_spyware !blk_BL_warez all [ !blk_BL_adv !blk_BL_aggressive !blk_BL_dating !blk_BL_drugs !blk_BL_gamble !blk_BL_hacking !blk_BL_movies !blk_BL_news !blk_BL_politics !blk_BL_porn !blk_BL_radiotv !blk_BL_socialnet !blk_BL_spyware !blk_BL_warez all ]
```

and that's what gets stored as the value of the `Target Rules` box.

---

When I was trying to figure this out, I unknowingly found myself in `vim` replicating the same two lists that make up the GUI by taking the value of `Target Rules`, splitting it into the lists inside and outside the brackets, and taking each of the flat lists and placing them vertically beside one another, then I realized what was going on.

Comment: Still there has to be a better way to do this....since you can't just paste it into the field, you have to go through each of the dropdowns and set them!!!!  I'd rather just generate a string and paste it into the `Target Rules` box to set it.

Comment: `Target Categories` really ought to be named `Inside Time Range` and `Target Categories for off-time` should be `Outside Time Range` (but there's likely more functionality involved here)